# Show menus from an existing plugin in a custom Perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I'm packaging my own Eclipse product. I'm including a third party plugin, PluginA, whose menu contribution is only displayed when the active perspective is Debug. I'd like this menu to be displayed also in a perspective I've created, MyPerspective, from my own plugin, PluginB.

I can't modify PluginA, but I can see the plugin.xml manifest, shown below, which shows how it configures it's menus. Its using the menu's visibleWhen attribute and checking the activePerspective is equal to DebugPerspective.

/PluginA/plugin.xml

```
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="plugina.handlers.PluginAHandler"
            name="PluginA Menu Item"
            id="PluginA.commands.menuitem">
      </command>
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="PluginA Menu">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
               <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
                  <equals value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugPerspective"/>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
            <command
                  commandId="PluginA.commands.menuitem"
                  style="push"/>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

The following is the manifest from my plugin which shows how I've created my own perspective, MyPerspective.

/PluginB/plugin.xml

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="pluginb.MyPerspectiveFactory"
            id="PluginB.myperspective"
            name="MyPerspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
```

When I run the product containing the above 2 plugins I see PluginA Menu on the menu bar only when the active perspective is Debug. I can't see the menu when in MyPerspective.

What I've tried. I added a redefinition of the PluginA menu in PluginB and added in my perspective.

/PluginB/plugin.xml

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="PluginA Menu">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
               <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
                  <equals value="PluginB.myperspective"/>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
            <command
                  commandId="PluginA.commands.menuitem"
                  style="push"/>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

This works but is less than idea because:

1. its duplicating code.
2. In "Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective > Menu Visibility"
   the "PluginA Menu" node is duplicated.

What can I add to PluginB that will force PluginA Menu to be shown in MyPerspective and not produce duplicates in the Customize Perspective dialog? I'm happy to add declarative statements to /PluginB/plugin.xml and/or runtime code to /PluginB to achieve this.

Comment: I think what you have is probably the best that can be done.

Comment: Hi greg-449, thanks for your thoughts. How do you suggest I use SO to mark this question?

Comment: I would leave it for a while, someone else may still have a good idea.

Comment: The method of specifying when a menu/view is visible in a particular perspective using the visibleWhen test seems pretty inflexible and can't easily be changed by a 3rd party. What is the recommended way of constraining visibility of menu/views to a particular perspective which allows user configuration?

Comment: The issue of using "visibleWhen" has been raised as a Platform UI bug: [Bug 505886 - Cannot customize visibility of toolbar items when they are using visibleWhen clause](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=505886)