# How to add debug items to toolbar for my custom perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, toolbar

I have a custom perspective which has a unique view. I would like to add debug items [image] when i switch to my perspective. I assume i should add those into my plugin.xml with this extension point ="org.eclipse.ui.menus" but i dont know how to specify to these buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add existing items to a perspective use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point.

You probably want the `actionSet` element of this extension point. You will have to do some research to work out what the existing action set id is.

You may need to Reset the perspective to get your changes to show.

Look in the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` plugin for its action set ids. One of these is `org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugActionSet`

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="your perspective id"> 
        <actionSet id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugActionSet"/> 
     </perspectiveExtension> 
</extension>
```

Comment: can you provide me an example if possible? Because i want only debug items and i do not think i should create a class to refer while having the extension. Maybe id names for those debug toolbar items?

Comment: perspectiveExtensions doen't require a class

Comment: actionsets are deprecated for ten years

Comment: @Basilevs I am aware of that, but there doesn't seem to be an alternative for perspectiveExtensions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568927/show-menus-from-an-existing-plugin-in-a-custom-perspective ?